# Click event not firing in jQuery Mobile?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Bg9Zx/5/

Relevant code:

```
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" id="locate-me">
<input type="checkbox" name="loc" id="loc" />
<label for="loc">Locate me</label>
</fieldset>
$("#loc").click(function(){
   alert('locate clicked!');
});
```

Why isn't the .click() event firing? Works perfectly fine if I don't reference jQuery Mobile.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are referecing it wrong. #loc refers to an ID of an element use this instead.

```
<label class="test" for="loc">Locate me</label>

$(".test").click(function(){
   alert('locate clicked!');
});
```

Comment: Oh I see what the problem is - in horizontal checkboxes in jQuery Mobile the checkbox itself isn't visible, only the label, so I need to pick up the click event on the label. Thanks!

Comment: how to get the checked property?

Comment: You mean the checked checkbox? $(".test:checked") will get you the checked checkbox

Answer (score 0):

Probably because your jQuery code is not wrapped in script tags. Try the following :

```
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" id="locate-me">
<input type="checkbox" name="loc" id="loc" />
<label for="loc">Locate me</label>
</fieldset>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#loc").click(function(){
   alert('locate clicked!');
});
</script>
```

Hope that helps.
Dave

Comment: Sorry, I just posted it that way for convenience. See the fiddle.

Comment: Ah, ok :-) - have not worked with jQuery Mobile, so was just taking a stab at the first thing that jumped out at me