# Jquery mobile click event not working - DOM Prob?

Tags: jquery, checkbox, click

tried a few combos of this the latest set of code is attached. In short I run my javascript from a separate file to the html and all I am trying to do is set up some code to watch when a checkbox is changed to run some logic on it.

Tried watching by .document.userdetails.signal, #signal ( added the class for that ) and just plain signal.

I would appreciate some guidance as I've looked at lots of examples many within the same html file so that why I think its the way I am trying to address the button.

```
<form id="userdetails" name="userdetails" action="javascript: savesettings()" >
       <p>
        <p>
        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
          <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
            <input name="signal" type="checkbox" class="custom" id="signal" value="1" checked="true" />
            <label class="signal" for="signal">Traffic Data</label>
            </legend>
</div>
```

And the Javascript

```
   $(".document.userdetails.signal").click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   alert('signal clicked!');
});
```

Thanks

Terran

EDIT - Was using this example last - [Click event not firing in jQuery Mobile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6421047/click-event-not-firing-in-jquery-mobile)

EDIT2 - http://forum.jquery.com/topic/calling-a-script-when-button-clicked Added $(document).ready so now $(document).ready(".document.userdetails.signal").click(function(e){........ seems to notice change when I open app - I guess I need to find the right target now as Jquery recreates checkboxes etc.

EDIT 3 - Jasons solution although comments from other contributors around the target are useful.

```
$(function() {
   $("#userdetails").on("change","#signal",function(eventObj) {
        //do code here. 
        eventObj.preventDefault();
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `click` event will work for the checkbox, but in general if you want to run javascript on change, use the `change` event instead. Ive included an example using `change` incase you want to copy-paste the code for a select box or textfield

```
$(function() {
   $("#userdetails").on("change","#signal",function(eventObj) {
        //do code here. 
        eventObj.preventDefault();
   });
});
```

..edit in response to comment..

```
    $(function () {
        $("#trafficdata").toggle(function () {
            alert('First handler for .toggle() called.');
        }, function () {
            alert('Second handler for .toggle() called.');
        });


        $("#userdetails").on("click", "#signal", function (eventObj) {

            eventObj.preventDefault();

            $("#trafficdata").click();

        });
    });
```

Comment: Jason - that worked thanks.... out of interest ( and having tried it )  is toggle allowed to be used in this way - ie $(function() {
   $("#userdetails").on("toggle","#trafficdata",function(eventObj) {
        eventObj.preventDefault();
  alert('First handler for .toggle() called.');
}, function() {
    e.preventDefault();
       alert('Second handler for .toggle() called.'); 
 
   });
}); - Had a quick go and no joy so I'm assuming there are a limited amount of events to be used in the format you suggested ?

Comment: I've updated the code with what I think you want to do. Basically I've defined a toggle function on traffic data, and when userdetails is clicked, the toggle function is executed on a different div

Comment: Its not a very good example though, I dont have enough information about what you want to do, if you could make a jsfiddle I can help you out.

Comment: Jason - thanks for that I'll have a look..... at the moment I am trying to put some logic behind buttons used in JQM... I'm currently self teaching so I'm still understanding some of the basics for which your examples are really helpful. For some reason the buttons seemed harder than the sliders which I can read and then refresh but thats all part of the fun I suppose :)

Comment: Jason - just a quick note to say thanks - that toggle script works like a charm. T

Answer (score 1):

`$(".document.userdetails.signal")` is looking for an element with three classes like `class="document userdetails signal"`.

Try `$("#signal")`:

```
$(function() { // shorthand for doc ready
    $(document).on('click','#signal',function(e) { // use .on in jquery 1.7
        alert('hello');
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Comment: Backticks `\`` format inline code, `Ctrl+K` formats code blocks :)